# Using arcpy.mp to edit TEXT_ELEMENTS with no success

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layouts, text

I'm attempting to take a user input in a script tool to modify the text within text elements on a layout. The following is the code I am using:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"S:/Initiatives/Mailings/MailOuts.aprx")
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Buffer Map")[0]

mapType = lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT", "Map Type")[0]
mapType.text = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

location = lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT", "Location")[0]
location.text = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

schedule = lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT", "Schedule")[0]
schedule.text = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
```

I don't receive an error when I run the script tool but the text elements remain empty when given user input.

Answer (score 2):

There's 1 problem in your tool for sure.
You don't actually save the changes you've made. If the code you've supplied is the entire tool, you're operating on a APRX on disk (not the active session). As such, your code could possibly be working 100% correctly, however when you open the APRX after the tool has run, you don't see the changes because you didn't save it.

You can try adding this as the last line:

```
aprx.saveACopy(r"S:/Initiatives/Mailings/MailOutsUpdated.aprx")
```

or just `aprx.save()`.

The other possible issue is your code is not actually finding the elements. For example, if you don't have a `TEXT_ELEMENT` named `Map Type`, the setting of the **mapType.text** property isn't going to do anything. (Although I'd expect if it didn't find anything, you'd get an error trying to do this step). I bring up this point as you may want to add some **AddMessage** to help understand the behavior. For example:

```
mapType = lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT", "Map Type")[0]
arcpy.AddMessage("The Map Type element is currently: {}, and will be updated to: {}".format(mapType.text, arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
mapType.text = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
```